# Add query limit to firestore from outside of client side

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to add some listener/trigger to my `firestore` database from outside of the application? such as cloud functions or something like this that will see if more than 15 results are queried = break or something like this to limit the queries?

I want to do something like this but from outside of my application code:

```
db.collection( "DB" )
        .whereArrayContains( "TitleArray", sq ).limit( 15 )
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    DOING SOMETHING
                }
            }
        } );
```

One more thing, Is there a way to do it for specific queries? For example, I query this collection in different cases and in one of them I had like to limit to 30 and in the other to 15:

```
db.collection( "DB" )
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo( "Title", s.toString() ).whereLessThanOrEqualTo( "Title", s.toString() + "\uF7FF" ).limit( 30 ).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    DO SOMETHING
                }
            }
        } );
```

Thank you

Comment: No, you cannot do that. You need to update the app to the latest version and after that, implement [Android In-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates), for example.

Comment: Yes, I did the in-app updates in the newer version but I asked more about implementing some triggers instead of how to force update.

Comment: If you want to ensure a user always specifies a specific limit, you can do so in security rules with `allow list: if request.query.limit <= 10;`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#evaluating_constraints_on_queries

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, good to know =]. I cant understand tho, the example you gave means that only users who have .limit(10) in their client code will be able to get results or even if users have .limit(20) will be able to get results but it will cut the reads at 10? I mean, does it force the limit or don't let the user to read if the limit is other then 10?

Comment: [Security rules never filter the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) themselves, but merely ensure operations are only allowed if they meet all rules. So a read with a limit of 20 would be rejected, as would a read without any limit at all.

Comment: Got it, Thank you very much.